# how are new bitcoins created

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, blockchain.info

I have read that new bitcoins are generated by a competitive and decentralized process called "mining" i want to know how the first coin was generated? From where is it genrated? Mining is just a prosses of authenticating a transaction right? From where do the new coins come from?

Comment: Go to a blockchain explorer like https://mempool.space/, pick any block and at the top of the list of transactions you will see what's called a "coinbase transaction" that creates new bitcoins and pays them out as a reward to the miner of the block. All bitcoins were originally created this way.